# Importing raster layer under Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ubuntu

I am using QGIS 2.18 with Ubuntu 16.04 and with Windows 7.

I can import a raster layer under Windows 7. 
It does not work under Ubuntu 16.04.

I got a message telling me that the file cannot be recognized.
Why ? Shall I import a special library under Ubuntu?

Comment: I never had any problems with raster import. You should tell us at least what format of raster file do you have. Maybe then you'll get answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/125264)

Comment: Which raster file type do you want to import?

Comment: Have a look to wich GDAL version you have in both system

Answer (score 0):

How many layers does your project have? There are file number defaults in Linux that are different from Windows. If these messages appear after loading a number of layers you may need to follow this procedure:

open a terminal window

sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf

scroll down to the bottom of the file and add the following line:

{asterisk} soft nofile 10000

(type an actual asterisk instead of {asterisk} because this stupid editor keeps turning an asterisk into a bullet)

save and exit

restart